# Google maps. Кнопки в инфоокнах

Tags: google-maps, карты, google-maps-api

Есть карта. На ней создан маркер и у него есть инфоокно. Суть в том что по примеру mapsengine.google.com хочу иметь возможность удалять Маркер из инфоокна(см. картинку)

код типа `$('#clearMarker').click(function(){markerNew.setMap(null);});`
не срабатывает, видимо потому что я не могу достучаться до DOM-элементов карты

Картинка для пояснения
https://twitter.com/energiya_by/status/370204858252402688/photo/1

Comment: Может есть возможность отследить нажатие на кнопку-корзину через Event Listeners?